# Codeigniter with Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar integration

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, calendar

when I integrated the Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar into my codeigniter project, everything is showing except the calendar itself

I already edited the paths to the external js files but it's still not working, although the bootstrap-calendar works when I opened its index file... I found a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUeEkuYcZGs) in youtube but I'm having a hard time since I don't speak spanish

Answer (score 0):

for those who have the same problems, check the posted video tutorial, you'll see a link to the video owner's github file and you can just adopt his codes so the bootstrap-calendar will work